# Cannot find disco.jar dependency for Maven Project

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, jar

I've just started helping my professor out for his research project and I'm trying to get it set up on my local windows computer. I'm stuck with this error:

> Failed to execute goal on project tornado: Could not resolve
>   dependencies for project tornado:tornado:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: Failure
>   to find com.disco:disco:jar:10.2.0 in http://clojars.org/repo was
>   cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted
>   until the update interval of clojars.org has elapsed or updates are
>   forced

Notes:

- It's a maven project being run on eclipse.
- I've tried multiple ways of adding the disco-2.0.jar file to the build path but I'm not sure if that's what I'm meant to be doing or if it's even the right file, although I haven't found any other disco file within the project directories.
- I've tried mvn clean install -U to see if it may just have been a problem with resetting the maven project.

Answer (score 1):

Well the log reads is clear and you could verify it as well:

> Failure to find com.disco:disco:jar:10.2.0 in http://clojars.org/repo

If you navigate to the https://clojars.org/repo/com/ there is no `disco.jar` available there. Hence the failure.

Probably this could be some local jar that might need to be build either locally or required by its owner to be pushed(`mvn deploy`) to clojars in another case.

Also `mvn clean install -U` help you fetch the latest of SNAPSHOT, in your case this would fetch the latest `tornado:tornado:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT` but that fails further sicne it specifies the `com.disco:disco:jar:10.2.0` as dependency which is not found anywhere for your build to proceed.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make the `disco-2.0.jar` available from a Maven repository. If you have a Nexus or Artifactory, upload it there. Alternatively, you can install it into the local repository of your computer using the `install:install-file` goal.

Furthermore, it is possible to define local directories as additional Maven repositories, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/28762617/927493.